# Moving elements from one place to another

Tags: actionscript-3

Im trying to move elements from one place to another place by randomly telling where to go from an array. But it is not acting as I was hoping it would.

the code is this

```
public class Main extends MovieClip
{
    private var positions:Array = [ 0, 100, 200 ];//different X positions

    public function Main()
    {
        for( var i:int = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            var box:Sprite = new Sprite();
            box.graphics.beginFill( Math.random()*0xffffff );
            box.graphics.drawRect( 100* i, 0, 80, 80);
            box.graphics.endFill();
            this.addChild( box );
            box.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onBoxClick);
        }
    }

    private function onBoxClick( ev:MouseEvent ):void
    {
        var currentObj:Sprite = ev.currentTarget as Sprite;

        var randomNumber:int = Math.random() * positions.length;

        currentObj.x = positions[ randomNumber ];
        currentObj.y = 200;

        positions.splice( randomNumber, 1 );

    }
}
```

as you can see i remove the X position that was given so that 2 elements can have the same position on the stage.But what the code does is it takes the current X position of the element and it adds to that the new X position. So if i click on **element 1** and get **position 2**, click on **element 2**  and get **position 1** and click on **element 3** and get **position 0** it would be this:

```
element1.x (0)   + 200 = 200;
element2.x (100) + 100 = 200;
element3.x (200) + 0   = 200;
```

and they will be all in the same spot ( 1 over other).

**and what I want is to do This:**

```
element1.x (no matter where it is ) + 200 = 200;
element2.x (no matter where it is ) + 100 = 100;
element3.x (no matter where it is ) + 0   = 0;
```

I tried doing this

```
currentObj.x = 0 + positions[ randomNumber ];
```

or

```
currentObj.x = stage.x + positions[ randomNumber ];
```

but then it (the current element) still counts its current location as the '0' and adds to it.

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line :

```
box.graphics.drawRect( 100* i, 0, 80, 80);
```

By this :

```
box.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 80, 80);
box.x = 100 * i;
```

It should work better then.

Your problem is you're drawing from a displaced point in the "box". So, when you're moving it's x, the displacement is summing up.

Drawing it at a 0 point will allow you to remove that offset.